# How to use Pattern Attribute on Textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to use Pattern attribute to do validation on text box.

When ever user entered any of these  .....i want to show some validation message.

So i created that element as follows:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="/(<!|&#|<\?|<|>)/" title="Required" required />
```

When ever i entered any text it is showing the alert...

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using the wrong pattern. In HTML patterns, you don't need an opening and closing delimiter. Also, the browser checks, if the entered text MATCHES the pattern, but you would need the exact opposite (if I understood it correctly). Try something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="^((?!(<)|(<!)|(<\?)|(&#)|(>)).)*$" title="Required" required />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```